# Dynamic type for function parameters with extraction of predefined types

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if it's possible to create dynamic type that would replace two params, such as in `on: (eventName: EventName, callback: (data: any) => void) => void` with something closer to this `on: (DynamicParams<EventName>) => void`, so it could extract `callback's` type from a predefined set and use it instead of `any` type.

I think it would be easier to explain with some code.

Say, I have set of different types of events:

```
const events = ['loaded', 'changed'];

type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> = ArrayType[number];

type EventName = ArrayElement<typeof events>
```

and a function that runs only when a specific notification has been emitted;

```
const on = (eventName: EventName, callback: (data: any) => void) => {}
```

But I want to be able to use this function with callback that accepts different parameter types, without checking for the type manually and without any casting, for example:

```
on('loaded', (list: Entry[]) => {
  // do something with loaded array of elements;
}

on('changed', (index: number) => {
  // do something with index of a changed entry;
}
```

Is there a way to create a mapped type that would accept EventName and return a specific type to a given event?

Something like that:

```
const on(eventName: EventName, DynamicMethod<'eventName'> => void) => {}

const on(DynamicParams<'eventName'>) => {}
```

Assume, I would need to replace event object and create a type in its place, instead:

```
type events = [
  {
    name: 'loaded',
    method: (list: Entry[]) => void

  },
  {
    name: 'changed',
    method: (index: number) => void
  }
]
```

But I'm not sure how to extract name values (not types of the values).

Comment: So [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJXOgN)? You may face some type issues when implementing the function (the body) with these kinds of things, though.

Comment: @caTS, Thank you. I think it would work perfectly for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a map of event names to their data type:

```
type EventMap = {
    loaded: Entry[];
    changed: number;
};
```

You can make `on` generic:

```
const on = <E extends EventName>(eventName: E, callback: (data: EventMap[E]) => void) => {}

on('loaded', (list) => {
//            ^? Entry[]
});

on('changed', (index) => {
//             ^? number
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJXOgN)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make this work:

Using call signatures:

```
interface OnEvent {
  (eventName: 'loaded', callback: (list: Entry[]) => void): void;
  (eventName: 'changed', callback: (index: number) => void): void;
}

const on: OnEvent = (eventName, callback) => {
    // Choose how to register the event here...
}
```

Or function overloads:

```
function on(eventName: 'loaded', callback: (list: Entry[]) => void): void;
function on(eventName: 'changed', callback: (index: number) => void): void;
function on(eventName: string, callback: (data: any) => void) {
    // Choose how to register the event here...
}
```